Computed property from VueX store does not update component
I have a component that lists entries of an array of posts (it's stored as projects in the store). When created the component dispatches a action to the store that fetches the data and mutates the resulting data into the state. Which works fine and the component shows the computed property of posts as populated (in Vue panel), but the template refuses to re-render its content.
Component
<template>
 [...]
  <CardGrid v-if="posts.length">
    <Card 
      v-for="post in posts"
      :key="post.id"
      :type="post.projekttype"
      :title="post.projekttitle" 
      :content="post.description"
    />
  </CardGrid>
  [...]
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex';

import Card from '@/components/Theme/Card.vue';
import CardGrid from '@/components/Theme/CardGrid.vue';

import utils from '@/utils/utils';

export default {
  name: 'Grid',
  moduleScheme: {
    [...]
    settings: {
      dataSource: 'project',
    }
  },
  components: {
    Card,
    CardGrid
  },
  props: {
    moduleId: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters([
      'getPosts',
      'getCurrentPageModule',
    ]),
    moduleSettings: function () {
      return this.getCurrentPageModule(this.moduleId).settings;
    },
    posts: function () {
      return Array.from(this.getPosts(this.moduleSettings.dataSource));
    },
  },
  methods: {
    loadData: async function () {
      this.$store.dispatch('loadData', {
        dataSource: this.moduleSettings.dataSource,
      });
    },
  },
  created () {
    this.loadData();
  }
}
</script>

Store (Posts)
import Vue from 'vue';
import { posts } from '@/utils/fetch';
import router from '@/router';

const postStore = {
  state: {
    [...]
    allPosts: {
      [...]
      project: [],
    },
  },
  mutations: {
    mutateAllPosts(state, payload) {
      Vue.set(state.allPosts, payload.dataSource, [...payload.posts]);
    },
    [...]
  },
  getters: {
    getPosts: (state) => (dataSource) => state.allPosts[dataSource],
   [...]
  },
  actions: {
    [...]
    loadData: async ({ commit }, settings) => {
      if (settings.dataSource === 'project') {
        const filter = {
          [...]
        }

        const response = await posts.get.all(settings.dataSource, filter);

        commit('mutateAllPosts', {
          posts: response,
          dataSource: settings.dataSource
        });
      } else {
        const response = await posts.get.all(settings.dataSource);

        commit('mutateAllPosts', {
          posts: response,
          dataSource: settings.dataSource
        });
      }
    },
    [...]
}

export default postStore;

Store (Modules)
import Vue from 'vue';
import store from '@/store';

import { modules } from '@/utils/fetch';

const modulesStore = {
  state: {
    modules: {},
    currentPageModules: [],
    changedModules: []
  },
  mutations: {
    mutateCurrentPageModules(state, payload) {
      Vue.set(state, 'currentPageModules', payload);
    },
    mutateCurrentPageModule(state, payload) {
      const currentPageModule = Array.from(state.currentPageModules).find(module => module.id === payload.module);

      Vue.set(currentPageModule.data, payload.contentName, payload.content);
    },
    mutateCurrentPageModuleSettings(state, payload) {
      const currentPageModule = Array.from(state.currentPageModules).find(module => module.id === payload.module);

      Vue.set(currentPageModule.settings, payload.contentName, payload.content);
    },
    clearCurrentPageModule(state, payload) {
      state.currentPageModules.splice(state.currentPageModules.findIndex(module => module.id === payload), 1);
    },
    moveCurrentPageModule(state, payload) {
      const temp = state.currentPageModules[payload.root];

      Vue.set(state.currentPageModules, payload.root, state.currentPageModules[payload.target]);
      Vue.set(state.currentPageModules, payload.target, temp);
    },
    mutateModules(state, payload) {
      state.modules[payload.pageId] = payload.modules;
    },
    mutateChangedModule(state, payload) {
      state.changedModules.push(payload);
    },
    clearChangedModules(state) {
      state.changedModules = [];
    },
    resizeCurrentPageModuleWidth(state, payload) {
      const currentPageModule = Array.from(state.currentPageModules).find(module => module.id === payload);

      currentPageModule.data.width = !currentPageModule.data.width;
    }
  },
  getters: {
    getCurrentPageModules: state => state.currentPageModules,
    getCurrentPageModule: state => id => {
      const module = state.currentPageModules.find(module => module.id === id);
      return module;
    },
    hasChanges: state => state.changedModules.length > 0,
  },
  actions: {
    loadCurrentPageModules: async ({ commit, state }, payload) => {
      store.dispatch('setLoading', { data: 'modules', status: true });
      
      const modulesByPage = state.modules[payload] ?? await modules.get.byPageId(payload);

      store.dispatch('setLoading', { data: 'modules', status: false });

      commit('mutateCurrentPageModules', modulesByPage);

      commit('mutateModules', {
        pageId: payload,
        modulesByPage
      });
    },
    changeModule: ({ commit, state }, payload) => {
      commit('mutateCurrentPageModule', payload);

      if (!state.changedModules.includes(payload.module)) {
        commit('mutateChangedModule', payload.module);
      }
    },
    changeModuleSettings: ({ commit, state }, payload) => {
      commit('mutateCurrentPageModuleSettings', payload);

      if (!state.changedModules.includes(payload.module)) {
        commit('mutateChangedModule', payload.module);
      }
    },
    resizeModuleWidth: async ({ commit, state }, payload) => {
      commit('resizeCurrentPageModuleWidth', payload);

      if (!state.changedModules.includes(payload)) {
        commit('mutateChangedModule', payload);
      }
    },
    clearChangedModules: ({ commit }) => {
      commit('clearChangedModules');
    },
    createModule: async ({ commit, state }, payload) => {
      const response = await modules.post.create(payload);
      commit('mutateCurrentPageModules', [ ...state.currentPageModules, response ]);
    },
    removeModule: async ({ commit }, payload) => {
      await modules.post.remove(payload);
      commit('clearCurrentPageModule', payload);
    },
    updateModules: async ({ commit, state }) => {
      store.dispatch('setSaving', true);

      await state.changedModules.forEach(async changedModule => {
        const data = state.currentPageModules.find(module => module.id === changedModule).data;
        const settings = state.currentPageModules.find(module => module.id === changedModule).settings;
        const position = state.currentPageModules.findIndex(module => module.id === changedModule);
        await modules.post.update(changedModule, { data: { ...data }, settings: { ...settings }, sort: position });
      });

      store.dispatch('setSaving', false);
      store.dispatch('addAlert', { type: 'success', message: 'Gespeichert.' });

      commit('clearChangedModules');
    },
    moveModule: async ({ commit, state }, payload) => {
      const modulePosition = state.currentPageModules.findIndex(module => module.id === payload.module);
      const targetModule = state.currentPageModules[modulePosition + payload.direction].id;

      const modulePositions = {
        root: modulePosition,
        target: modulePosition + payload.direction,
      };

      commit('moveCurrentPageModule', modulePositions);


      [targetModule, payload.module].forEach(id => {
        if (!state.changedModules.includes(id)) {
          commit('mutateChangedModule', id);
        }
      })
    }
  }
}

export default modulesStore;

Populated posts property

I tried replacing the mapGetter and use the state directly resp. using VueX's mapState helper.
    ...mapState({
      posts (state) {
        return state.posts.allPosts;
      }
    }),

This led to the data showing up in the component. But as soon as I tried filtering for it, by adding moduleSettings.dataSource it disappears again. Since I'd like to just get the project array from the state I thought it would be better to call it via an getter with included filter.
I suspect I got any misconception of vue's reactivity model anywhere but can't find it.

Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . getCurrentPageModule is missing. A reproduction will help as this is much easier to solve when there's a possibility to debug. That there's Vue.set suggests there's a problem with non-reactive data that could be related.

@EstusFlask Thanks for your response! I added the store that's responsible for handling the different modules. Don't know if this helps or only more questions raised, since the whole app is pretty big I can't show it all … So I also returned an static Object from moduleSettings. With no observable change.

This is still unfortuntately not an isolated reproduction that we can try.

I didn't spot the obvious problem with reactivity yet. Did you place Vue.set() in mutateAllPosts for a reason? It's not supposed  to make a difference, considering that allPosts.project already exists. It needs to be reproducible with api calls replaced with mocked data.
